Langchain Dir loader from google drive throwing errors
I am trying to load html files from google myDrive. I am trying this on colab. I was able to load the drive, when I use DirectoryLoader, it is seeing file names but it throws an error as follows. Btw, I gave permissions to comment for anyone (even though colab asks permission through the google account to load myDrive). The error is cryptic and I couldnt find any other one who went through this (when I googled it). Appreciate any help please
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive')

loader = DirectoryLoader(path = os.getcwd(), glob="datasets/opp/*.html", show_progress=True, use_multithreading=True, loader_cls = UnstructuredHTMLLoader)
documents = loader.load()

error:
ERROR:langchain_community.document_loaders.directory:Error loading file /content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/opp/745_eatchicken.com.html
 63%|██████▎   | 72/115 [00:00<00:00, 336.85it/s]ERROR:langchain_community.document_loaders.directory:Error loading file /content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/opp/503_buffalowildwings.com.html
ERROR:langchain_community.document_loaders.directory:Error loading file /content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/opp/807_lodgemfg.com.html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_community/document_loaders/unstructured.py in __init__(self, mode, post_processors, **unstructured_kwargs)
     58         try:
---> 59             import unstructured  # noqa:F401
     60         except ImportError:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unstructured'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_community/document_loaders/unstructured.py in __init__(self, mode, post_processors, **unstructured_kwargs)
     59             import unstructured  # noqa:F401
     60         except ImportError:
---> 61             raise ImportError(
     62                 "unstructured package not found, please install it with "
     63                 "`pip install unstructured`"

ImportError: unstructured package not found, please install it with `pip install unstructured`

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


I added pip install unstructured and that particular exception went away (my bad I didnt see it was not included out of 40+ installs :D). it errored saying it doesnt know punkt and asked me to download it from nltk which i did and i hit another error (cant find PY3_tab) while doing loader.load(). This looks like onion peeling... BTw, the error loading file still exists
